# In XCode 4, how do you change the number of tabs in a UiTabBarViewController?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, xcode4

I've been looking at this new interface for a while now and I can't figure out how to add or remove tabs from the tab bar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1 - Open your xib-file inside Xcode. Show the right sidebar (Navigator | Utility). At the bottom of this bar should be all Interface Builder objects (i.e. UITabBarItem, UILabel, ...). Now drag a UITabBarItem to your View.
*If you don't see these objects: At the bottom is a small cube. press it and you'll see it.*

2 - Right-click on your file and open in external editor. This opens Interface Builder. If it won't work you can open your file directly with the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

You ask this question in the Apple Developer Forums where you can talk about confidential information (read: NDA software). Xcode4 is not yet available for public consumption, therefore it's still under NDA.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean. XCode 4 GM is out and available. Before that XCode 4 beta's were available as well.

Comment: I don't know why we should ask this in the Apple Dev Forums?! Most of iOS Developer here know Xcode 4. And it should be possible to get the answer right here. 

Xcode 4 GM seed
Posted: February 3, 2011
Build: 4A278

Comment: It is still under NDA until they publish the final version (not the GM seed). Apple is well within their right to disable your dev account for talking about it if they wanted to.

Comment: @Andrei - Xcode 4 GM is still prerelease software because it is only available to registered developers, not the world at large.  You may wish to read the developer agreement you signed to become an iOS developer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49009/as-an-ipad-iphone-ipod-touch-developer-what-cant-i-ask-or-answer-on-stack-overf/49366#49366 .  Apple has specific forums set up for discussing prerelease software like this among other NDA'd developers.

Answer (score 1):

I also work around on find out how to set the tabitem in Xcode4, I found you just drag the controller to the tabitems, the select the uiview of this tab item and set it's class. Xcode on longer support set tab item at the inspect panel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Tab Bar was created in XCode (which it should be if you created a Tab Bar project) click on your Main Window.xib to view it.

Click the disclosure indicator to see the hierarchy of objects (if it isn't that way already).
It should look something like this:

[image]

The number of view controllers that you have underneath it is the number of tabs you have.
In this case the view controller is a Navigation Controller, and the View Controllers are children of it.

Answer (score 0):

If u r using Story board .........
Just do this ...
and i am telling for Xcode 4.3

just add view controller from the libirary you can add as much as you like..
then link those views with your main view controller...
as you will link with it ....
it will automatically pop up relationship with main controller and thus a tap will be added automatically in your main controller...
you can visit this link ....
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvvJzkJcsew"